# How to render casted shadow on surface only

Tags: transparency

How can i render a character + the shadow it cast on a surface but not the surface itself?

I would use it to

- Render my background only once (if nothing moves in background) so i would be saving a lot of time
- Better effects with transparency gif

Answer (score 1):

- Cycles Render
  Select the surface object, go to Object / Cycles settings and check **Shadow Catcher**.
  In Render / Film, check **Transparent**.
- Blender Render
  Select the surface object, go to Material / Shadow, check **Shadows Only**.
  In Render / Shading / Alpha, select **Transparent**.